# when you do activeRecord.save does the transaction commit or is when the method exits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 3, when you do activeRecord.save does the transaction commit or is when the method exits ?

so what I'm trying to figure out is if the MySQL is written right after save! or it's save after I exit the define black

```
def something
  1000.times do
       o = Order.new(:name => "Tomas")
       o.save
  end
end
```

Comment: It will save when you call "save" or "save!" :) Nothink more, nothing less. Maybe except some case with transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably read up a bit on the [ActiveRecord object callback chain](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html); it explains what is going on under the hood with your objects.

Basically, when you call save, an ActiveRecord::Base object will go through all the callbacks in the order the documentation lists them, you can see where the commit takes place (in between steps 6 and 7 as of my writing this).  ActiveRecord even exposes a callback after the commit happens in case you want some conditional logic when you're sure something has been committed to the database, but generally we trust that if `save` returns true, everything is fine.

So to explicitly answer your question, a commit happens *during* your save call, not when you exit the method.

Comment: To the OP: Just to be safe you can use `save!` to raise validation errors rather than just have `save` return a boolean.